# Unknown keyword "mumps_mem_percent"

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, mathematical-optimization, pyomo, nonlinear-optimization

I am using Pyomo to model an optimization problem. I am getting an error if I tried to set the value of "mumps_mem_percent" option.

```
opt = pyo.SolverFactory('ipopt')
opt.options['mumps_mem_percent'] = 10e3
opt.solve(mdl)
```

RROR: Solver (ipopt) returned non-zero return code (1)
ERROR: Solver log: Ipopt 3.11.1: Unknown keyword "mumps_mem_percent"

Am I doing something wrong? I checked the options of IPOPT and I found this option. Any suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you have to do is create an `ipopt.opt` file, which specifies the desired options, and place it in your working directory. For instance, for your case, something like this could work (found the solution [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pyomo-forum/2ChhRsc4xrU), but did not test it though):

```
with pyo.SolverFactory("ipopt") as opt:
    opt.options.option_file_name = "ipopt.opt"
    with open("ipopt.opt", "w") as f:
        f.write("mumps_mem_percent 10e3\n")
    opt.solve(mdl)
```

More information about option files for IPOPT can be found here: https://coin-or.github.io/Ipopt/OPTIONS.html

Alternatively, someone on [Github](https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/issues/206), also mentioned that using the "OF_" prefix with your options could work.

Comment: Thanks @gmavrom for your response. But I am using IPOPT with MUMPS to solve optimization problems as expected. The problem appears if I tried to change some parameters of MUMPS like the one mentioned in the post.

Comment: Hey @TamerIbrahim, I have edited my answer with something that seems to be a bit more of a plausible solution. Have a look and let me know if it works!